# Using self. to set but not to access causes issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, self, accessor

I am currently getting confused why the following works in some cases but not others. When using the following code:

```
NSString *currentLoc = [[NSString stringWithString:sceneName] retain];
self.currentLocation = currentLoc;
[currentLoc release];
```

This should overwrite my `NSString *currentLocation, of type (nonatomic, retain)` with the new value. Why can I now not access this value by doing the following:

```
NSString *test = currentLocation;
```

When debugging I see that test is set to a random array, so the pointer must be pointing at something completely different. I have checked through the code and the currentLocation variable is only set here. If I use the following:

```
NSString *test = self.currentLocation;
```

Then the correct value is now shown, can someone explain why currentLocation / self.currentLocation are treated as different objects, I understand that self. uses the accessor but surely if set correctly they should both point to the same value?

EDIT 1: (All code)

.h

```
NSString *currentLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentLocation;
```

.m

```
@synthesize currentLocation;

NSString *currentLoc = [[NSString stringWithString:sceneName] retain];
    self.currentLocation = currentLoc;
    [currentLoc release];

if (currentLocation != nil && singleton.storyLocation != nil)
    {
        if (boolMoviePlayed == false && [singleton.storyLocation isEqualToString:currentLocation]) // crash here due to current location being set to an array
            [buttonPlayMovie setHidden:!textVisible];
    }

    self.currentLocation = nil; // viewDidUnload
    [currentLocation release]; // dealloc
```

EDIT 2: (Updated code, still crashes)

So this time I've tried to access the code in the way it was set, as seen below:

```
if (self.currentLocation != nil && singleton.storyLocation != nil)
{
    if (boolMoviePlayed == false && [singleton.storyLocation isEqualToString:self.currentLocation])
        [buttonPlayMovie setHidden:!textVisible];
}
```

However, this time I get a crash where the variable seems to be unset, even though it is never changed at any point during this process (see code in EDIT 1).

EDIT 3:

Now I am getting confused, I thought I had the answer but I just plain don't. I tried using Erics suggestion:

@synthesize currentLocation = _currentLocation;

Then I made sure all access to currentLocation was set using self.currentLocation = xyz. Now when it comes to the dealloc method, I was always warned not to use self. in the dealloc. But this means all my values are nil as currentLocation has not been set. Is it safe to use [self.currentLocation release] or how can I fix my issues?

EDIT 4:

As far as I can tell, you then use [_currentLocation release] within the dealloc, if I am wrong please correct me, if not I will go down this route for now as it seems to work.

Comment: Have you create a ivar as currentLocation?

Comment: Just added all the related code which may make what I'm doing a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at how you synthesized as well as your ivars. In reality currentLocation is referring to the iVar directly, while self.currentLocation, could be pointing to a different variable if you synthetized it like this for example:

```
@synthesize myVar = _myVar
```

and then you also had in your interface

```
interface {
  myVar
}
```

In this scenario you would see the issue described.

Comment: Let me edit my question, and I will put all the code down relating to that object, may make it easier :)

Comment: For dealloc it is safer to use [_currentLocation release] or more enerally [iVar release]. You could also do self.myIvar = nil, which both releases and sets to nil, however this may lead to complications such as KVO notifications being send. Therefore in general do not use the setter in dealloc method, it will not cause issues 99% of the time, but it is safer to just use [iVar release];

Answer (score 1):

`currentLocation` is a variable, `self.currentLocation` is a fancy way to call property getter  (a method) `- (NSString*)currentLocation`.

Obviously you are using the property to store the value and there is no connection set between the variable and your property.

You should inspect the row where you are synthesizing the property `currentLocation`.

Answer to edit3:

The `init` methods and `dealloc` are the only two places when a property ivar should be accessed directly. In `dealloc` you usually write directly `[_currentLocation release]`. However there is a big discussion about it. In general it is correct to just put `self.currentLocation = nil` into `dealloc` but you have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@synthesize currentLocation = _currentLocation`.

Comment: No, just @synthesize currentLocation; Is this wrong, and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: it allows you to distinguish the property from the instance variable.

Comment: Ah okay, so if I'm using the code in edit 2, is there any reason my application should still be crashing even though the variable is definitely not being changed / released?

Comment: you should synthesize as I do in my answer and retry if you're using self.instanceVariable to access a property

Comment: If I use this approach, should I be using self. to set and get the variable?

Comment: yes, you should only use self.property within the class if you are synthesizing like @synthesize property = _property. Else, just cast it as an instance variable and not a property and don't use self.

Comment: I would suggest a new question just pertaining to that issue.

Comment: There is no reason to change it if he is using `@synthesize currentLocation;` There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple :

property = getter + setter + iver

**Exp. #1:**

.h

```
NSString *yourName;  //iver
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myName; //property
```

.m

```
@synthesize myName;   

-(void)someMethod{
    self.myName = @"Mike";

    NSString * name = self.myName; // name will be "Mike"
    name = myName; // name will be "Mike"

    name = yourName;   // name will be null
}
```

Here yourName, self.myName and are three different things :

yourName is a iver
self.myName is a getter or setter in two different cases
myName is a iver

Now I want to connect yourName iver to myName property.
Let see  how in Exp. #2

Exp. #2

.m

```
@synthesize myName = yourName;   

-(void)someMethod{
   self.myName = @"Mike";

    NSString * name = self.myName; // name will be "Mike"

    name = yourName;   // name will be "Mike"

    yourName = @"James";

   name = self.myName ; // name will be "James"

}
```

Here you cant use myName iver.

Comment: property = getter + setter (unless it's readonly where it's only getter). The ivar association only applies if you synthesize

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. But you have shown bits and pieces of code (there is not even a complete method or class) and it's really hard to tell what's going on. The error must be from something else. All this talk about changing the variable name is completely irrelevant -- there is nothing wrong with using the same variable name.